# Unable to log in, unable to load install.php

Tags: php, typo3

I had a task to set up Typo3 with LDAP extensions. I did so and everything was kinda working. Yesterday I was also asked to enable HTTP2. I did so via this tutorial https://www.tecmint.com/enable-http2-in-apache-on-ubuntu/. Afterwards I noticed that I can't login to backend any more. I tried everything, I also disabled the LDAP Extension in PackageStates.php, I tried changing password hash in database but the url/typo3 login form still keeps saying the credentials are incorrect.

To cap it all I am also unable to reach typo3/install.php - it results into gray screen with rotating "Initializing" forever. The frontend of website still works though, I am just unable to get to backend even after disabling LDAP and resetting password via DB [by this tutorial.](https://hostlantern.com/clients/knowledgebase/1015/How-can-I-reset-my-Typo3-administrative-password-.html)

I am running on Debian, Apache 2.4 with its php 7.4 module.

I was so desperate that I tried to reinstall the app but when I try to I can't even load install.php, it results just in a gray screen. But as I said - DB and php is working, since it loads the frontend page even with content.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Anyway this sounds like more of a sysadmin problem than a programming problem. Maybe try the Server Fault stackexchange instead

Comment: BTW i tried to downgrade to php 7.2 and still same problem :/

Comment: Like I said, this is a sysadmin problem, we don't really do those here. Try Server Fault. And drop the "urgent" stuff, it won't do you any favours, we're all volunteers, we'll help if and when we can, not on your schedule. Sorry you're stressed but it's not our emergency.

Comment: I assume you're using TYPO3 10.4. Is your installation composer based? If yes, try to clear all files in `var/cache/`. If it's not composer based, clear `typo3temp/var/cache/` instead. Did you check the Apache error log?